# trying to parsing latitude and longitude through xml parsing and annotate all locations that i've in my dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xml, core-location

Its my xml file in that I've data

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locations>
  <location id="1">
    <title>United Arab Emirates</title>
    <latitude>23.424076</latitude>
    <longitude>53.847818</longitude>
  </location>
  <location id="2">
    <title>Afghanistan</title>
    <latitude>33.93911</latitude>
    <longitude>67.709953</longitude>
  </location>
  <location id="3">
    <title>Australia</title>
    <latitude>-25.274398</latitude>
    <longitude>133.775136</longitude>
  </location>
  <location id="4">
    <title>Bangladesh</title>
    <latitude>23.684994</latitude>
    <longitude>90.356331</longitude>
  </location>
</locations>
```

===============================
Its my .m file in that I've written the code

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self dataParsing];
NSLog(@"%@",locSMutArr);
[self setUpMapMethod];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)dataParsing{
NSString *strFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xmlPractise1" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *dataObj=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strFile];
NSXMLParser *parseObj=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:dataObj];
parseObj.delegate=self;
[parseObj parse];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma  mark - NSXMLParser Delegate

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(nullable NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(nullable NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)attributeDict{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"locations"]) {
    locSMutArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"location"]){
    locMutDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
if (refString==nil) {
    refString=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
}
else{
    refString=[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",refString,string];
}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(nullable NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(nullable NSString *)qName{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"latitude"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"longitude"]) {
    [locMutDic setValue:refString forKey:elementName];
}
else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"location"]){
    [locSMutArr addObject:locMutDic];
}
 refString=nil;

}
-(void)setUpMapMethod{

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D CLLocObj;
    CLLocObj.latitude=[locSMutArr indexOfObject:[locMutDic valueForKey:@"latitude"]];
    CLLocObj.longitude=[locSMutArr indexOfObject:[locMutDic valueForKey:@"longitude"]];
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocObj, 100, 100);
    [_mapOutlet setRegion:viewRegion];
    MKPointAnnotation *annotaionObj=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
    [annotaionObj setCoordinate:CLLocObj];
    [_mapOutlet addAnnotation:annotaionObj];
    }

}
@end
```

I want to use for loop for creating CLLocationCoordinate2D object for all value of lat and lon that in dictionary of xml .
And also annotate there all locations .
That all

============================
It my .h file where I've declare all objs.

```
 @interfaceViewController:UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate,CLLocationManagerDele gate,MKMapViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *locSMutArr;
    NSMutableDictionary *locMutDic;
    NSMutableString *refString;
    NSMutableArray *mutLatArr;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapOutlet;

@end
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the Code which works for me

```
import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *locations;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableDictionary *location;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *openElement;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [self parseData];
    [self logData];
    [self setupMap];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)logData{
    NSLog(@"%@",_locations);
}

-(void)parseData{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"xml"];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(nullable NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(nullable NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)attributeDict{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"location"])
        _location = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"locations"])
        NSLog(@"Start");
    else
        _openElement = elementName;

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if(![string containsString:@"\n"])
        [_location setObject:string forKey:_openElement];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(nullable NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(nullable NSString *)qName{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"location"])
       [_locations addObject:_location];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundAttributeDeclarationWithName:(NSString *)attributeName forElement:(NSString *)elementName type:(nullable NSString *)type defaultValue:(nullable NSString *)defaultValue{
    NSLog(@"%@",attributeName);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)setupMap{
    for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in _locations){
        CLLocationCoordinate2D CLLocObj;
        CLLocObj.latitude=[(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
        CLLocObj.longitude=[(NSString*)[dict valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
        MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion=MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocObj, 100000, 100000);
        [_mapView setRegion:viewRegion];
        MKPointAnnotation *annotaionObj=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
        [annotaionObj setCoordinate:CLLocObj];
        [annotaionObj setTitle:[dict valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [_mapView addAnnotation:annotaionObj];

    }
}
```

This is the output of my NSMutableArray with the NSMutableDictionary

```
(
        {
        latitude = "23.424076";
        longitude = "53.847818";
        title = "United Arab Emirates";
    },
        {
        latitude = "33.93911";
        longitude = "67.709953";
        title = Afghanistan;
    },
        {
        latitude = "-25.274398";
        longitude = "133.775136";
        title = Australia;
    },
        {
        latitude = "23.684994";
        longitude = "90.356331";
        title = Bangladesh;
    }
)
```